# How to resolve 'no matching mac found error' when I try to ssh

Tags: openssh, hmacsha1

The following is the error I am getting:
no matching mac found: client hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 server hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting this error because the client and the server could not agree upon a hashing algorithm for message authentication code.

More information here:
https://blog.tinned-software.net/debug-ssh-connection-issue-in-key-exchange/

Comment: You might want to audit the settings of your ssh server with https://github.com/arthepsy/ssh-audit

Comment: @bbaassssiiee That project was abandoned. [Here](https://github.com/jtesta/ssh-audit) is a maintained fork.

Answer (score 22):

I have struggled to this problem for decent time before understanding the basics and root cause. Sharing the experience so it can help someone.

I was trying to ssh to a target server and getting error like below

```
$ ssh -A <someTargetServerNameOrIP>
Unable to negotiate with XX.XX.XX.XX port 1234: no matching MAC found.   
Their offer:   
hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,
umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com
```

The root cause of this error is on your source machine the supported MAC doesnt contain the MAC from target server.

to see this run in command line on your machine

```
$ ssh -Q mac   # output would be something like
hmac-sha1
hmac-sha1-96
hmac-sha2-256
hmac-sha2-512
hmac-md5
hmac-md5-96
umac-64@openssh.com
umac-128@openssh.com
```

So now in order to connect to target server with their choice of mac which your server doesn't support you have to explicitly provide one of the mac supported by target server. For e.g. we take **hmac-sha2-512** from the error message and try to connect, and it will be connected

```
$ ssh -m hmac-sha2-512 -A <someTargetServerNameOrIP>
```

Another variant of the problem is the mismatch in cipher which looks like below

```
$ ssh -A <someTargetServerNameOrIP>       
Unable to negotiate with XX.XX.XX.XX port 1234: no matching cipher found.   
Their offer: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
```

The root cause is mismatch of cipher

Check your supported cipher by

```
$ ssh -Q cipher   # output would be something like
3des-cbc
aes256-cbc
rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
aes128-ctr
aes192-ctr
aes256-ctr
aes128-gcm@openssh.com
aes256-gcm@openssh.com
```

So now in order to connect to target server with their choice of cipher which your server doesnt support you have to explicitly provide one of the cipher supported by target server. For e.g. we take aes128-cbc from the error message and try to connect, and it will be connected

```
$ ssh -c aes128-cbc -A <someTargetServerNameOrIP>
```

More details on this can be found
https://diego.assencio.com/?index=688f3a536f63c43566c94f0818d9ecf3

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: it worked for me and I was able to update my ~/.ssh/config file to include the clause `MACs              hmac-ripemd160` to allow accessing the system without the -m

Answer (score 4):

in centOS/RHEL 7 server while trying to access the server via TMA pulse secure tool and getting the below error on /var/log/secure

```
[root@rhellinuxserver ~]# cat /var/log/secure| grep -iE "no matching"
Aug 24 07:02:07 rhellinuxserver sshd[29958]: Unable to negotiate with 172.21.112.111 port 16899: no matching MAC found. Their offer: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com [preauth]
Aug 24 07:15:24 rhellinuxserver sshd[30702]: Unable to negotiate with 172.21.112.111 port 33541: no matching MAC found. Their offer: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com [preauth]
```

To fix the issue edit the sshd_config file as mentioned below

```
 # cat -n /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep -i MAcs
```

Find the line

```
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com
```

Replace it with

```
MACs hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160
```

This will add following extra MACs algorithms.

```
hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160
```

Restart the SSHD service now

```
 systemctl restart sshd
```

now able to access the server find the success result in /var/log/secure log file.

```
cat /var/log/secure| grep -i Accepted
Aug 24 07:18:24 rhellinuxserver sshd[548]: Accepted password for username from 172.21.112.111 port 53776 ssh2
```

**Important Note:**

Do not use this two weak ciphers **aes256-cbc** & **aes128-cbc**

This may allow an attacker to recover the plaintext message from the ciphertext.

Disable CBC mode cipher encryption and enable CTR or GCM cipher mode encryption.

Below is the steps to disable SSH weak ciphers **aes256-cbc** & **aes128-cbc**

**Step 1:** Remove **AES-128-CBC** & **AES-256-CBC** on this file.

```
/etc/crypto-policies/state/CURRENT.pol
```

**Step 2:** Remove aes256-cbc & aes128-cbc on this file.

```
/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensshserver.config
```

**Step 3:** Restart/Reload the sshd service

```
$ sudo systemctl restart sshd
$ sudo systemctl status sshd
```

**Step 4:** Now you can take the ssh connection without weak ciphers aes256-cbc & aes128-cbc

```
$ sudo ssh -vvv user-name@IP-Address
```

For more information's refer this **CVE-2008-5161**

Answer (score -2):

Latest putty client solved the issue.

Comment: Which version, was this issue mentioned in the release notes?