# Unable to FTP to EC2 instance with an elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon Linux EC2 instance with proper security groups. I was able to FTP to that instance to move my application code from local to EC2. After everything was properly setup I created an Elastic IP for that instance. But now I am not able to FTP to the instance using the Elastic IP, putty works fine.
Any pointers to resolve this will be appreciated.

Comment: As an alternative to FTP, you can use SCP (for Windows it is WinSCP) which works over ssh and does not require FTP.

Comment: I have tried both WinSCP and FileZilla  and both of them does not connect.

Comment: The fact that you can connect via SSH/PuTTY indicates that network connectivity is good. The only thing that would cause FTP to not function is either a missing entry in the Inbound Security Group for Port 21, or some strange NACL settings, or the FTP daemon is not running on the instance. If you have changed any NACLs, reset them to "Allow All" in both directions. If you SSH into the instance and try to use FTP locally (`ftp localhost`), does it work?

Comment: After 3 days of debugging I am finally able to get it working. I was getting 'No matching Mac found error' when I was connection through Winscp. I followed the steps in this link- [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51501496/how-to-resolve-no-matching-mac-found-error-when-i-try-to-ssh [link] and with that Winscp started working but putty failed. So now I am using ssh in powershell instead of putty.